# Facebook share and open graph image bug?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

In different post across internet and even in [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/open-graph-object/) there is such rule to correct share image throughout facebook sharer:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/lamb-full.jpg">
```

And I did sharing to facebook from my site exactly this way, but it doesn't work correct. Looks like facebook ignores my open graph image tag (see it in source code of the page) if other images are present on the page.
[Link to example page](http://socratify.ru/stanislav-ezhi-lets.c1) and screenshot how to reproduce

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the OpenGraph Debugger to get insights about what's wrong from the FB persepactive:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsocratify.ru%2Fstanislav-ezhi-lets.c1

Apparantly, the og:url, og:desc and og:title are missing.

Comment: Do you think og:url is required for scrapping correct og:image? If so - it's strange...

Comment: I guess with your application, you're currently not only sharing an image, but a URL